# Writing a routine to create sequential records

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to write a routine which will allow me to take dated events (records) in a table which span accross a set time frame and in the cases where no event took place for a specific day, an event will be created duplicating the most recent prior record where an event DID take place.

For example:  If on September 4  Field 1 = X, Field 2 = Y and Field 3 = Z and then nothing took place until September 8 where Field 1 = Y, Field 2 = Z and Field 3 = X, the routine would create records in the table to account for the 3 days where nothing took place and ultimately return a table looking like:

Sept 4:  X - Y - Z
Sept 5:  X - Y - Z
Sept 6:  X - Y - Z
Sept 7:  X - Y - Z
Sept 8:  Y - Z - X

Unfortunately, my level of programming knowledge although good, does not allow me to logically conclude a solution in this case. My gut feeling tells me that a loop could be the correct solution here but I still an not sure exactly how.  I just need a bit of guidance to get me started.

Comment: still I would suggest you to write an example with data.

Comment: Nothing, sorry to say..  Only countless hours of thinking about it.

Comment: Since you haven't provided us with the table schema, it's a little hard to help you.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure the best way to communicate this.  The table i am using in the example above has 4 Fields: (1) The Date, (2) Field 1, (3) Field 2 and (4) Field 3...

Comment: Prior to running the routine the table would resemble this:

    Sept 4  X   Y   Z
    Sept 8  Y   Z   X

AFter running the routine the table would resemble

    Sept 4  X   Y   Z
    Sept 5  X   Y   Z
    Sept 6  X   Y   Z
    Sept 7  X   Y   Z
    Sept 8  Y   Z   X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```
Sub FillBlanks()
    Dim rsEvents As Recordset
    Dim EventDate As Date
    Dim Fld1 As String
    Dim Fld2 As String
    Dim Fld3 As String
    Dim SQL As String

    Set rsEvents = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblevents ORDER BY EventDate")
    'Save the current date & info
    EventDate = rsEvents("EventDate")
    Fld1 = rsEvents("Field1")
    Fld2 = rsEvents("Field2")
    Fld3 = rsEvents("Field3")
    rsEvents.MoveNext
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        ' Loop through each blank date
        Do While EventDate < rsEvents("EventDate") - 1 'for all dates up to, but not including the next date
            EventDate = EventDate + 1 'advance date by 1 day
            rsEvents.AddNew
            rsEvents("EventDate") = EventDate
            rsEvents("Field1") = Fld1
            rsEvents("Field2") = Fld2
            rsEvents("Field3") = Fld3
            rsEvents.Update
        Loop
        ' get new current date & info
        EventDate = rsEvents("EventDate")
        Fld1 = rsEvents("Field1")
        Fld2 = rsEvents("Field2")
        Fld3 = rsEvents("Field3")
        rsEvents.MoveNext
        ' new records are placed on the end of the recordset,
        ' so if we hit on older date, we know it's a recent insert and quit
    Loop Until rsEvents.EOF Or EventDate > rsEvents("EventDate")
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect Tom! The field examples I gave you were simplified but I applied your logic successfully. I will post the final product shortly so you can see your work in action.  If you have a chance, 1 additional question:I didn't consider in my question that there is another field which Identifies the particular project.  Given that there are multiple projects in the record set, i quickly realised that before I could use your code, I had to create a query to isolate only the records regarding the project of choice.  Can we include some type of query in your code to avoid the workaround?

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. Example?

Comment: Have a look in my final answer at the field called "ID Project".  That is the ID number of the individual projects in the record set.  Due to the fact that i want the result to only return values for one specific project at a time, i had to create a workaround query to isoltate the records according to "Project ID".  Prior to doing so, i noticed that the code you provided seemd to pick up random (perhaps) project IDs and mix up the created records between one project and the next. Sorry if i cant make it more clear for you. Don't worry about it if you don't understand what i mean. Againthanks!

Comment: Tom, i'm not sure how the Bounty works. How do I ensure that you get the points???

Comment: There should be be a bounty award icon next to my answer. Just click it. Thanks. Here's all the help section on bounties: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Hi Tom. Excuse me but there is one thing about your code that doesnt work..  If all existing records are sequential, then the code goes into an error message. In other words, if no records are missing and don't need to be created, the loop doesnt work...  Would you have any words of wisdom on how to resolve?

Comment: ps the run time error message is 3021. No current record

Comment: Added 1 line of code above the first Do. Not the most elegant solution, but I'm tired tonight.

Answer (score 1):

With no details about your specifics (table schema, available language options etc), iI guess that you just need the algorithm to pick up. So here's a quick algorithm with no safeguards.

```
properdata = "select * from data where eventHasTakenPlace=true";
wrongdata = "select * from data where eventHasTakenPlace=false";
for each wrongRecord in wrongdata {
    exampleRecord = select a.value1, a.value2,...,a.date from properdata as a 
    inner join
    (select id,max(date)
     from properdata
     group by id
     having date<wrongRecord.date
     ) as b
     on a.id=b.id

    minDate = exampleRecord.date;
    maxDate = wrongRecord.date -1day; --use proper date difference function as per your language of choice.
    for i=minDate to maxDate step 1day{
         dynamicsql="INSERT INTO TABLE X(Value1,Value2....,date) VALUES (exampleRecord.Value1, exampleRecord.Value2,...i);
         exec dynamicsql;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Command109_Click()

    On Error GoTo errhandler

    Dim rsEvents As Recordset
    Dim EventDate As Date
    Dim ProjID As String
    Dim Fld1 As String
    Dim Fld2 As String
    Dim Fld3 As String
    Dim Fld4 As String
    Dim Fld5 As String
    Dim Fld6 As String
    Dim Fld7 As String
    Dim Fld8 As String
    Dim Fld9 As String
    Dim Fld10 As String
    Dim Fld11 As String
    Dim Fld12 As String
    Dim Fld13 As String
    Dim Fld14 As String
    Dim Fld15 As String
    Dim Fld16 As String
    Dim Fld17 As String
    Dim Fld18 As String
    Dim Fld19 As String
    Dim Fld20 As String
    Dim Fld21 As String

    Dim st_sql As String
    Dim Sql As String

    Me.Refresh

    Set rsEvents = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblProjectMasterListHistory02 ORDER BY LastUpdateDate")
    'Save the current date and info

    EventDate = rsEvents("LastUpdateDate")
    ProjID = rsEvents("ID Project")
    Fld1 = rsEvents("OverallPrincipleStatus1")
    Fld2 = rsEvents("OverallPrincipleStatus2")
    Fld3 = rsEvents("OverallObjectiveStatus")
    Fld4 = rsEvents("OverallObjectiveStatus2")
    Fld5 = rsEvents("OverallDependencyStatus1")
    Fld6 = rsEvents("OverallDependencyStatus2")
    Fld7 = rsEvents("OverallAssumptionsStatus1")
    Fld8 = rsEvents("OverallAssumptionsStatus2")
    Fld9 = rsEvents("OverallConstraintsStatus1")
    Fld10 = rsEvents("OverallConstraintsStatus2")
    Fld11 = rsEvents("ObjectivesScope")
    Fld12 = rsEvents("ObjectivesResources")
    Fld13 = rsEvents("ObjectivesProjectPlan")
    Fld14 = rsEvents("ObjectivesEffort")
    Fld15 = rsEvents("ObjectivesBenefits")
    Fld16 = rsEvents("ObjectivesResourceMobilisation")
    Fld17 = rsEvents("ObjectivesMetrics")
    Fld18 = rsEvents("OverallRiskStatus1")
    Fld19 = rsEvents("OverallRiskStatus2")
    Fld20 = rsEvents("GovernanceStatus1")
    Fld21 = rsEvents("GovernanceStatus2")

    rsEvents.MoveNext

    Do

     ' Loop through each blank date

        Do While EventDate < rsEvents("LastUpdateDate") - 1 'for all dates up to, but not including the next date
            EventDate = EventDate + 1 'advance date by 1 day
            rsEvents.AddNew
            rsEvents("LastUpdateDate") = EventDate
            rsEvents("ID Project") = ProjID
            rsEvents("OverallPrincipleStatus1") = Fld1
            rsEvents("OverallPrincipleStatus2") = Fld2
            rsEvents("OverallObjectiveStatus") = Fld3
            rsEvents("OverallObjectiveStatus2") = Fld4
            rsEvents("OverallDependencyStatus1") = Fld5
            rsEvents("OverallDependencyStatus2") = Fld6
            rsEvents("OverallAssumptionsStatus1") = Fld7
            rsEvents("OverallAssumptionsStatus2") = Fld8
            rsEvents("OverallConstraintsStatus1") = Fld9
            rsEvents("OverallConstraintsStatus2") = Fld10
            rsEvents("ObjectivesScope") = Fld11
            rsEvents("ObjectivesResources") = Fld12
            rsEvents("ObjectivesProjectPlan") = Fld13
            rsEvents("ObjectivesEffort") = Fld14
            rsEvents("ObjectivesBenefits") = Fld15
            rsEvents("ObjectivesResourceMobilisation") = Fld16
            rsEvents("ObjectivesMetrics") = Fld17
            rsEvents("OverallRiskStatus1") = Fld18
            rsEvents("OverallRiskStatus2") = Fld19
            rsEvents("GovernanceStatus1") = Fld20
            rsEvents("GovernanceStatus2") = Fld21

            rsEvents.Update

        Loop

        ' get new current date and info
        EventDate = rsEvents("LastUpdateDate")
        ProjID = rsEvents("ID Project")
        Fld1 = rsEvents("OverallPrincipleStatus1")
        Fld2 = rsEvents("OverallPrincipleStatus2")
        Fld3 = rsEvents("OverallObjectiveStatus")
        Fld4 = rsEvents("OverallObjectiveStatus2")
        Fld5 = rsEvents("OverallDependencyStatus1")
        Fld6 = rsEvents("OverallDependencyStatus2")
        Fld7 = rsEvents("OverallAssumptionsStatus1")
        Fld8 = rsEvents("OverallAssumptionsStatus2")
        Fld9 = rsEvents("OverallConstraintsStatus1")
        Fld10 = rsEvents("OverallConstraintsStatus2")
        Fld11 = rsEvents("ObjectivesScope")
        Fld12 = rsEvents("ObjectivesResources")
        Fld13 = rsEvents("ObjectivesProjectPlan")
        Fld14 = rsEvents("ObjectivesEffort")
        Fld15 = rsEvents("ObjectivesBenefits")
        Fld16 = rsEvents("ObjectivesResourceMobilisation")
        Fld17 = rsEvents("ObjectivesMetrics")
        Fld18 = rsEvents("OverallRiskStatus1")
        Fld19 = rsEvents("OverallRiskStatus2")
        Fld20 = rsEvents("GovernanceStatus1")
        Fld21 = rsEvents("GovernanceStatus2")

        rsEvents.MoveNext
        'new records are placed on the end of the recordset
        'so if we hit an older date, we know it's a recent insert and quit

    Loop Until rsEvents.EOF Or EventDate > rsEvents("LastUpdateDate")


errhandler:

End Sub
```